# how to pick from an array depending on a certain number

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

Lets say you use indexOf on an array to find all cases that say apple. If it comes back with three cases at positons 1, 2 and 3.

Now lets say there is an array = [10, 20, 30 ,40 ,50 ,60 ,70 ,80 ,90 ,100]

is there a way to use them cases 1,2 and 3 which come to 6. So is there a a way to go to position 6 "70" and produce that number. Depending on what the indexOf provides, is there a way to select that number from the array. Also if the indexOF produced 3.5 would there be a way to get 35 aka position 3.5.

Comment: The `.indexOf()` function returns just one number though

Comment: what if it was put through a loop

Comment: Yes, but to be clearer, the .indexOf() function returns a single integer. ;)

Comment: @RobRaisch How can multipe integers be returned

Comment: Also `.indexOf()` will never return a value that's not an integer, so `3.5` is impossible.

Comment: @taz1010 multiple numbers will never be returned from a single call to indexOf.  That's not how that method works.

Comment: They cannot without introducing a loop. I'm not completely clear on what you're asking. Are you looking to iterate over an array for the position of elements that match your search criteria, and then sum the returned indices the result of which will be used to locate an element in another array?

Comment: Also having an array and looking up apple; getting 1, 2, 3; summing those up to 6; and getting the 6th element from a second array (without any explanation as to why) makes no sense.

Comment: @RobRaisch Yes thats correct I believe. Whatever criteria matches, get the sum of that. Then whatever that sum is, go to that index position in an array and retirvee that value.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you can use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to get the sum of the indexes where a match to some search term occurs. Then you can use the result from the `reduce()` to access your array of numbers:

```js
let test = ["orange", "apple", "banana", "apple"];
let numbers =  [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90];

const getSumOfIdxs = (arr, str) =>
{
    return arr.reduce((acc, curr, idx) =>
    {
        if (curr === str)
        {
            if (acc < 0) acc += 1;
            acc += idx;
        }

        return acc;
    }, -1);
}

let res = getSumOfIdxs(test, "apple");
console.log("Sum of indexes: ", res);
console.log("Element from numbers: ", numbers[res]);

res = getSumOfIdxs(test, "hello");
console.log("Sum of indexes: ", res);
console.log("Element from numbers: ", numbers[res]);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Comment: Is there an edge case where no matches occur in the target array and so `acc === 0` which when applied to the numbers array will return a false result?

Comment: @RobRaisch You were right, I have taken care of that situation, `undefined` should be returned now if there is not match.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can - `filter` through the array and find all your `apple`s, then `map` out the indexes from the original array, `reduce` to one index, and get the item at that index.

```js
const arr = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100];

const appleNums = [20, 30, 40];

const resultingAppleNum = arr[arr.filter(e => appleNums.includes(e)).map(e => arr.indexOf(e)).reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr)];

console.log(resultingAppleNum);
```